# command 'extension.smartBackspace' not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

i clone a new repo, i can't delete what I write with the "delete" key, only in this project.

When I press the key I get a message from vs telling me:

> command 'extension.smartBackspace' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to remove this keyboard shortcut:

**1/ Go to key shortcut settings**

[image: Go to key shortcut settings]

**2/ search `backspace`**

**3/ Click to delete key combination linked to smart.backspace**

[image: click to delete key combination linked to smart.backspace]

I'm sorry my screenshots are in French , I hope it helps you anyway